# Samba partially working: can connect but cannot browse

Tags: fedora, samba

I have a machine I'm using as a HTPC, running Fedora 23. Up until recently, everything was working fine browsing and connecting other PCs on my network (I have a mix of Linux and Windows machines). Now, for some reason, I can no longer browse my samba shares from this PC. Connecting directly (by name or IP) works fine; pinging by name works fine. I made no changes; in fact I was away for a week with everything turned off and this problem seems to have surfaced upon my return.

I've tried a number of things--multiple times in various permutations--all to no avail:

- rebooting everything, including my router
- restarting smb.service and nmb.service
- temporarily disabling firewalld
- temporarily setting SELinux to permissive
- adding these lines to smb.conf:
- 1) *name resolve order = bcast host lmshosts wins*
- 2) *dns proxy= no*
- 3) *map to guest = bad user*
- testing the connection in a terminal with s*mbclient -d2 -L computername -U username* -- this works!

Also, I don't see any errors in the logs in /var/log/samba . So after hours of hitting my head on this, I'm very much stumped. At this point it's not so much a problem that I need to solve, since connecting directly works, but I'd like to understand this better and learn a little something.

Here is the output of `smbtree` from the HTPC that doesn't work (let's call it "WOMBAT"), alongside the output from two machines that do work (running openSUSE and Linux Mint).

```
# smbtree output from "WOMBAT":
# browsing smb shares from this machine does not work...
# however, connecting directly works, e.g., to smb://dog/shared
# Pinging any of the other machines by name also works.
HOME
\\WOMBAT                Samba Server Version 4.3.11
    \\WOMBAT\IPC$               IPC Service (Samba Server Version 4.3.11)
    \\WOMBAT\homes              Home Directories
\\                      OpenRG File Server


# smbtree output from working machine, "DOG":
HOME
\\WOMBAT                Samba Server Version 4.3.11
\\ROUTERUSB_FILESH      OpenRG File Server
\\DOG           dog server (Samba, Linux Mint)
    \\DOG\IPC$              IPC Service (dog server (Samba, Linux Mint))
    \\DOG\Shared2           Media2 on dog
    \\DOG\Shared            Media on dog
    \\DOG\print$            Printer Drivers
\\CAT                   Cat
    \\CAT\Video (F)         
    \\CAT\C$                Default share
    \\CAT\Shared-Cat-F      
    \\CAT\H$                Default share
    \\CAT\ADMIN$            Remote Admin
    \\CAT\F$                Default share
    \\CAT\Shared-Cat2       
    \\CAT\Shared-Personal   
    \\CAT\G$                Default share
    \\CAT\Shared-Video      
    \\CAT\C                 
    \\CAT\Shared-Cat-C      
    \\CAT\print$            Printer Drivers
    \\CAT\SharedDocs        
    \\CAT\IPC$              Remote IPC
    \\CAT\Other (G)         
\\CHIPMUNK              Samba 4.2.4-18.1-3668-SUSE-SLE_12-x86_64
    \\CHIPMUNK\IPC$             IPC Service (Samba 4.2.4-18.1-3668-SUSE-SLE_12-x86_64)
    \\CHIPMUNK\share            Shared files
    \\CHIPMUNK\print$           Printer Drivers
    \\CHIPMUNK\groups           All groups
    \\CHIPMUNK\users            All users
    \\CHIPMUNK\profiles         Network Profiles Service
\\PIG         


# smbtree output from working machine, "CHIPMUNK":
HOME
\\WOMBAT                Samba Server Version 4.3.11
\\ROUTERUSB_FILESH      OpenRG File Server
\\DOG           dog server (Samba, Linux Mint)
    \\DOG\IPC$              IPC Service (dog server (Samba, Linux Mint))
    \\DOG\Shared2           Media2 on dog
    \\DOG\Shared            Media on dog
    \\DOG\print$            Printer Drivers
\\CAT                   Cat
    \\CAT\Video (F)         
    \\CAT\C$                Default share
    \\CAT\Shared-Cat-F      
    \\CAT\H$                Default share
    \\CAT\ADMIN$            Remote Admin
    \\CAT\F$                Default share
    \\CAT\Shared-Cat2       
    \\CAT\Shared-Personal   
    \\CAT\G$                Default share
    \\CAT\Shared-Video      
    \\CAT\C                 
    \\CAT\Shared-Cat-C      
    \\CAT\print$            Printer Drivers
    \\CAT\SharedDocs        
    \\CAT\IPC$              Remote IPC
    \\CAT\Other (G)         
\\CHIPMUNK              Samba 4.2.4-18.1-3668-SUSE-SLE_12-x86_64
    \\CHIPMUNK\IPC$             IPC Service (Samba 4.2.4-18.1-3668-SUSE-SLE_12-x86_64)
    \\CHIPMUNK\share            Shared files
    \\CHIPMUNK\print$           Printer Drivers
    \\CHIPMUNK\groups           All groups
    \\CHIPMUNK\users            All users
    \\CHIPMUNK\profiles         Network Profiles Service
\\PIG
```

The only clue I've got is when running `systemctl status nmb -l` from the offending box (output below), my subnet doesn't look right. But I'm not sure about this--maybe it's fine--and I'm not sure how to confirm its correctness.

```
  ● nmb.service - Samba NMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nmb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-08-10 23:32:26 EDT; 2h 20min ago
   Main PID: 17468 (nmbd)
     Status: "nmbd: ready to serve connections..."
     CGroup: /system.slice/nmb.service
             └─17468 /usr/sbin/nmbd

  Aug 10 23:32:26 wombat.home systemd[1]: nmb.service: Supervising process 17468 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
  Aug 10 23:32:26 wombat.home systemd[1]: Started Samba NMB Daemon.
  Aug 10 23:32:26 wombat.home nmbd[17468]: [2016/08/10 23:32:26.084522,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  Aug 10 23:32:26 wombat.home nmbd[17468]:   STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
  Aug 10 23:32:49 wombat.home nmbd[17468]: [2016/08/10 23:32:49.120302,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  Aug 10 23:32:49 wombat.home nmbd[17468]:   *****
  Aug 10 23:32:49 wombat.home nmbd[17468]:   
  Aug 10 23:32:49 wombat.home nmbd[17468]:   Samba name server WOMBAT is now a local master browser for workgroup HOME on subnet 192.168.124.1
  Aug 10 23:32:49 wombat.home nmbd[17468]:   
  Aug 10 23:32:49 wombat.home nmbd[17468]:   *****
```

My next step is to try NFS instead (though that's side-stepping the issue), and after that, wipe the machine and start over. But even if that fixed it, I'd have learned nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a virtual network interface (`virbr0`). Samba was picking this up as the preferred interface, which was pointing to an invalid broadcast address. I guess since it saw itself as the only samba server running there, it set itself as the "local master browser".

See this excerpt from the output of `smbtree -d3`, and take note of the third entry with an erroneous "bcast" of "192.168.124.255":

```
Processing section "[global]"
added interface wlp0s20u6 ip=192.168.1.14 bcast=192.168.1.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
added interface enp3s0 ip=192.168.1.15 bcast=192.168.1.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
added interface virbr0 ip=192.168.124.1 bcast=192.168.124.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
```

Disabling the *libvitrd* service (`systemctl disable libvirtd`) got rid of that interface, which seems to have rectified the problem; now smbtree shows the other shares on the network.

Before disabling this interface, when I would check the status of nmb.service, I saw a message something like, "Samba name server WOMBAT is now a local master browser for workgroup HOME on subnet 192.168.124.255". This incorrect subnet is what led me to the incorrect interface; I saw its address when running `ifconfig`.

**EPILOGUE:** I am not sure how that interface came to be. If I understand correctly, it's a virtual NAT interface. I don't have Virtualbox, VMWare, etc. installed on this computer; I'm not sure what else might have enabled it. If someone cares to, please shed some light in a comment.